# observable with http request

Tags: angular, rest, http, angular6

I am using angular 6 into my project. Fetching data from rest and displaying data into the html. But I want to use observable if any data changes on rest, it will be auto reflect into the front end. could you please help me how to use observable with async pipe.

Comment: please post some code that you have tried

Comment: That isn't really possible unless your API is exposed as WebSockets.

Comment: are you looking for real time data (like changes being pushed from server to client) or just what to  reflect the changes to data in the view  after normal rest api call ?

Comment: if you are looking for real time data changes from server the you will need use something  websockets as @SiddAjmera mentioned .  check out https://feathersjs.com/   a  realtime API layer for modern applications

Answer (score 0):

Use Observable in HTML as mentioned below

```
<selector [property]="rows$ | async"> </selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular a basic **Service** class having `GET` API call contains the below code:

```
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get('<Your rest URL>');
  }
```

Here, `this.http.get()` will always return you an **Observable**, which you can subscribe inside your component class or as you want to use `async` pipe in your template, assign it to an **Observer**

For eg: -

Say **app.component.ts** file

```
  data$: any;

  constructor(
    private yourService: YourService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data$ = this.yourService.getData();
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of data$ | async"> {{item.someKey}} </ng-container>
```

Comment: but my question how to know rest data changes. currently I'm looking this blog https://fullstack-developer.academy/display-real-time-data-in-angular/. but unable to understand how to use observable.

Comment: one more question based on your example we dont need use "subscriber"

Comment: Then, in that case, you need to implement Web Sockets at your backend. Rest API wont help